# Pull links from incoming visitors (referrals) via Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, referrals

Is there a way to pull links from incoming visitors on a page (referrals)?  I essentially want to do some if statements.

***if user is from Nextag.com {do some javacode} else from Pricegrabber.com {do some javacode}.***

Before I can do the if statements I need to find out how that user got on our page (where did they come from).  I know google analytics does this but is there a way to hard code it on one page so I can do the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the referer URL with `document.referrer`, it is supported cross-browser.

It might not be set though based on the user's privacy preferences, firewall, etc. Some proxies also clear or fake it.

You can run some Regexes on the value or use `indexOf`, and do some actions based on them.

For example (not final code):

```
if (document.referrer.indexOf('nextag.com') != -1) {
     //user came from nextag.com
}
```

[MDC Docs on document.referrer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.referrer)

Comment: Thats the code I was looking for!  Thank you I will try and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `document.referrer` (assuming it is populated by the user's browser).

Answer (score 2):

Use the `document.referrer` property to get the originating URL, plus some basic pattern matching for validation:

```
var reURL = new RegExp("^https?:\/\/(www.)?nextag.com\/", "i");

if (document.referrer.length && reURL.test(document.referrer)) {
    alert("Hello, nextag.com!");
} else {
    alert("Hello, world!");
}
```